# How to make media query for 1024 x 600 and 1024 x 768 work separately?

Tags: html, css

I am using chrome's dev tools to test the website on different resolutions.

I have a separate media query for 1024 x 600 and 1024 x 768 but for some reason the 1024 x 768 is used for the 1024 x 600. If I delete the 1024 x 768 then it will use the 1024 x 600.

Here is the code I use for the media queries:

```
@media all and  (max-width:1024px),(max-height: 768px)
{
} 
@media all and  (max-width:1024px),(max-height: 600px)
{
}
```

Comment: When the page has a width of `800px`, which rules should apply, @10501411?

Comment: I have not made those rules yet. But it  will be 1280 x 800

Comment: As you progress in front end work you'll want to note that stacking tons of media queries isn't great. I recommend reading up on responsive front end development.

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because my websites needs to fit on one page with no scrolling. There is no other way without using media queries

Comment: Have you tried using Min-Height: 601px on the first one?

Comment: I tried that does not work.

Comment: I happen to believe you don't really understand when `@media all and  (max-width:1024px),(max-height: 768px)` applies. it means: apply these rules when the maximum device width is less or equal than 1024px or when the maximum device height is less or equal than 768px. First one is ***width***, second one is ***height***. I also think we're dealing with a classic case of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you please outline the problem you're trying to solve using the above technique?

Comment: What is your real problem? I doubt you want to use `@media` queries for fun. I think you're trying to overcome a design challenge. What is that challenge?

Comment: @Andrei create a vertically responsive web page, using vh  is not enough.

Comment: That's easy: `/* code here applies on all devices (A)+(B) */ @media(max-height: 600px) {/* (A) code here applies only when device height is less than 600px */} @media(min-height: 601px){/* (B) code here applies only when device height is more than 601px*/}`. Obviously, you can have more than just two.

Comment: Thanks I ended up figuring it out from reading mozilla

Answer (score 0):

You can create complex media queries by combining them with "and".
To limit the styles to devices with a screen, you can chain the media features to the screen media type:

(as for your question:)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 768px) {  }  
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 600px) {  }
```

Read about @media [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), and Good Luck!

Comment: I have gotten rid of using max-width and I am just using max-height. For some reason max-height:600px does not work at all. It is my smallest media query.

Comment: so maybe use just one: min-height: 601px? that mean that all style will apply to screens under 600px height, and all style on this role will apply to screens higher than 600px.